# Import-Excel module is not working

Tags: powershell

I want to import .xlsx file in powershell and for that I came to know that the cmdlet is Import-Excel  or Import-Xlsx), etc.
But these throw error when I try to run them in powershell 4.0, cmdlet not found.

How to use them? Also Install-Module is not working in Powershell 4.0?

Comment: On [https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) scroll down to Installation and read the instructions. Look for PowerSellGet or [PackageManagement PowerShell Modules](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51451) for the latter

Answer (score 0):

Below Powershell Function servers the purpose

```
function Import-Excel 

{ 

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)] 

    Param( 
        [parameter( 
            mandatory=$true,  
            position=1,  
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,  
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [String[]] 
        $Path, 

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)] 
        $Worksheet = 1, 

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)] 
        [switch] 
        $Force 
    ) 

    Begin 
    { 
        function GetTempFileName($extension) 
        { 
            $temp = [io.path]::GetTempFileName(); 
            $params = @{ 
                Path = $temp; 
                Destination = $temp + $extension; 
                Confirm = $false; 
                Verbose = $VerbosePreference; 
            } 
            Move-Item @params; 
            $temp += $extension; 
            return $temp; 
        } 

        # since an extension like .xls can have multiple formats, this 
        # will need to be changed 
        # 
        $xlFileFormats = @{ 
            # single worksheet formats 
            '.csv'  = 6;        # 6, 22, 23, 24 
            '.dbf'  = 11;       # 7, 8, 11 
            '.dif'  = 9;        #  
            '.prn'  = 36;       #  
            '.slk'  = 2;        # 2, 10 
            '.wk1'  = 31;       # 5, 30, 31 
            '.wk3'  = 32;       # 15, 32 
            '.wk4'  = 38;       #  
            '.wks'  = 4;        #  
            '.xlw'  = 35;       #  

            # multiple worksheet formats 
            '.xls'  = -4143;    # -4143, 1, 16, 18, 29, 33, 39, 43 
            '.xlsb' = 50;       # 
            '.xlsm' = 52;       # 
            '.xlsx' = 51;       # 
            '.xml'  = 46;       # 
            '.ods'  = 60;       # 
        } 

        $xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application; 
        $xl.DisplayAlerts = $false; 
        $xl.Visible = $false; 
    } 

    Process 
    { 
        $Path | ForEach-Object { 

            if ($Force -or $psCmdlet.ShouldProcess($_)) { 

                $fileExist = Test-Path $_ 

                if (-not $fileExist) { 
                    Write-Error "Error: $_ does not exist" -Category ResourceUnavailable;             
                } else { 
                    # create temporary .csv file from excel file and import .csv 
                    # 
                    $_ = (Resolve-Path $_).toString(); 
                    $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Add($_); 
                    if ($?) { 
                        $csvTemp = GetTempFileName(".csv"); 
                        $ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item($Worksheet); 
                        $ws.SaveAs($csvTemp, $xlFileFormats[".csv"]); 
                        $wb.Close($false); 
                        Remove-Variable -Name ('ws', 'wb') -Confirm:$false; 
                        Import-Csv $csvTemp; 
                        Remove-Item $csvTemp -Confirm:$false -Verbose:$VerbosePreference; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    End 
    { 
        $xl.Quit(); 
        Remove-Variable -name xl -Confirm:$false; 
        [gc]::Collect(); 
    } 
}
```

Hope this HElps!

Comment: You should probably mention this requires Excel to be installed (and besides, COM is not supported for unsattended automation purposes)